# Boolean column in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a boolean field as a column in my matrix, when I run the report this column is divided in 2 columns, one for "true" and one for "false". I want to show the "true" column only. how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly answering your question, you can set the **Column Visibility** of the column to be expression based, with the expression as something like:

```
=Not(Fields!YourField.Value)
```

[image]

[image]

Taking a step back, since you want to exclude all of a particular value, you could also consider applying a **Filter** at the DataSet or Tablix level to exclude all rows where your field is false.

Comment: You're welcome. If you find an answer helpful please consider upvoting and/or setting it as the accepted answer.